# Spring JPA Query Schema not found

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have created query to search for available rooms in a hotel, based on date interval and room type. 
I'm getting the following error when i run this query:

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "R" not found; SQL statement:

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

public interface RoomRepository extends JpaRepository {

```
    @Query(value = "
                SELECT Room r 
                FROM Room join r.bookings b    
                WHERE not ((b.beginDate >= :initDate And b.beginDate <= :endDate) or (b.beginDate >= :initDate And b.endDate <= :endDate) or (b.beginDate <= :initDate and b.endDate >= :endDate) and b.approved = true and r.roomType = :roomType)"
            , nativeQuery=true)
    public List<Room> findWithDates(@Param("initDate") Date initDate, @Param("endDate") Date endDate, @Param("roomType") long roomType);
}
```

Comment: are you sure your jpql-style-join is correct if you use nativeQuery=true?

Comment: @cproinger if i don't use nativeQuery=true the application gives a bunch of errors when booting

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT Room r 
>                   FROM Room join r.bookings b

Your alias should not be in the select statement

> SELECT r FROM Room r ..........

Also you dont really need the "select" if you select everything.

> from Room r ...

Should be enough

Comment: it still gives me the same error 
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema "R" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT r FROM Room r join r.bookings b WHERE not ((b.beginDate >= ? And b.beginDate <= ?) or (b.beginDate >= ? And b.endDate <= ?) or (b.beginDate <= ? and b.endDate >= ?) and b.approved = true and r.roomType = ?) [90079-188]

Comment: How does your jdbc url look like? Have you defined your schema name in it?

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:../data/mydb
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:update

are you reffering to this? @jvecsei

Answer (score 1):

If you use native query, then you should not use named parameters. The schema 'R' is the prefix to the table name in generated SQL. The schema prefix is added normally to the table specified by the URL parameter in the connection to the database. In your case it's different because you didn't use any schema connection. To use the native SQL query you should use `@NamedNativeQuery` like

### Using the annotation `@NamedNativeQuery`

> Native queries are defined through the `@NamedNativeQuer`y and
>   `@NamedNativeQueries` annotations, or `<named-native-query>` XML
>   element.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name="complexQuery",
    query="SELECT Room r 
                FROM Room join r.bookings b    
                WHERE not ((b.beginDate >= ? And b.beginDate <= ?) or (b.beginDate >= ? And b.endDate <= ?) or (b.beginDate <= ? and b.endDate >= ?) and b.approved = true and r.roomType = ?)",
    resultClass=Room.class
)
public class Romm { ... }

Query query = em.createNamedQuery("complexQuery", Room.class);
query.setParameter(1, initDate);
query.setParameter(2, endDate);
query.setParameter(3, initDate );
query.setParameter(4, endDate);
query.setParameter(5, initDate );
query.setParameter(6, endDate);
query.setParameter(7, roomType);

Room room = (Room) query.getSingleResult();
```

You can find more examples in the [Java Persistence/Querying](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying)